Flex strangely computes width when grid doesn't
The only difference here is parent, styles of subtree are completely the same.
Grid calculates the width of first element (section with green outline) correctly, but flex sets it to 0 and allows overflow (blue circle div). Playing with overflow or flex-shrink on section doesn't help.

Here is the code:


main {
  margin-top: .5em;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto 1fr;
}

section {
  outline: 1px solid green;
}

div {
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
}

#height:checked ~ main div {
  height: 100%;
}

aside {
  height: 75px;
  background: #F00A;
}
<input type="checkbox" id="height" checked="checked">

<main class="flex">
  <section>
    <div></div>
  </section>
  <aside>aside</aside>
</main>

<main class="grid">
  <section>
    <div></div>
  </section>
  <aside>aside</aside>
</main>



What I expect

Height of aside is taken as a height of main (it works)
Height of main is used as height of section because of flex/grid (it works)
Height of section is used as height of div because of height: 100% (it works: you can check by unchecking checkbox - size of div changes to 0 and circle disappears if height is not set)
Height of div is used as width of div because of aspect-ratio: 1 (it works: div is visible as a circle)
Width of div bounces back as width of section because div is in normal flow inside of the section (works with grid in Chrome but not in FF; never works with flex: green frame is collapsed to 0 width insted of surrounding blue circle like in grid)
Width of section recalculates flex/grid layout and aside shifts to the right of it (works in grid)

Questions
Should flex and grid behave the same way in this example?
Do I misunderstand how it should work with flex?
Is there a way to make flex behave like grid here?
I found out that in FF grid works the same way as flex - that means either FF or Chrome is wrong in calculating grid - who of them and why?
About "100% of what?"
It's ok to specify height in percents for subchildren of horizontal flex: https://jsfiddle.net/w3m7Ldrk/


main {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
  outline: 1px dotted red;
}

div {
  background: blue;
  width: 3em;
}
<main>
  <section><div style="height:25%"></div></section>
  <section><div style="height:50%"></div></section>
  <section><div style="height:75%"></div></section>
  <section><div style="height:100%"></div></section>
  <aside>1<br>2<br>3<br>4</aside>
  <section><div style="height:150%"></div></section>
</main>



Also in original example blue circle does definetely have height of section (green outline) only when checkbox is checked, so height: 100% works fine. That means, regardless specifying height on section solves the problem, lack of specific height on it can't be an answer about why it behaves like that.

@Paulie_D, that question is about the same behaviour, but it asks how to fix it, not why is it happening. I'm more focused on reasoning and flexbox logic and want to know how should it work and what's the difference with grid.

short answer: in flexbox you have two layers (flex container --> flex items) and in CSS grid three layers (grid container --> grid track --> grid items). 2 different algorithms so don't expect them to work the same.

@TemaniAfif, interesting, but would like a long answer. Also I found that in FF grid doesn't work either, so at least one of the browsers has a bug with grid (but I don't know which)...

none of them have bugs. Two different implementations leading to a different result for a specific use case. There is no Spec violation for both and for me FF is doing the right choice here.

@TemaniAfif, I thought spec is specific enough to have all browsers doing the same thing, isn't it? For me chrome's version seems more logical.

but FF is closer to the Spec in this case. The Spec doesn't describe all the specific cases and browser aren't obliged to closely follow the Spec as well.

Essentially, when combining flexbox and aspect-ratio a defined / computable height is needed. 100% in your original instance does not work because there is no original height. 100% of what?
Instead, give the parent the height.


main {
  margin-top: .5em;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  height: 75px;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  height: 75px;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto 1fr;
}

section {
  outline: 1px solid green;
}

div {
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
}

#height:checked~main div {
  height: 100%;
}

aside {
  background: #F00A;
}
<input type="checkbox" id="height" checked="checked">

<main class="flex">
  <section>
    <div></div>
  </section>
  <aside>aside</aside>
</main>

<main class="grid">
  <section>
    <div></div>
  </section>
  <aside>aside</aside>
</main>




but why it work for grid without straight height for container?

"100% of what?"- 100% of section as a flex child. It does work as circle has correct height in both cases. I'm more interested in why behaviour of grid differs from beheviour of flex. Seems like it should be logic of point 5 of my question, not point 3 which is visibly working right. I can specify heights in percents for subchildren in horizontal flex: https://jsfiddle.net/w3m7Ldrk/
